# Random Forest as best approach to this problem?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, random-forest

I am studying ML and want to practice building a model to predict stock market returns for the next day, for example based on price and volume of the preceding days.

The current values I have for each day:

```
M = [[Price at day-1, price at day 0, return at day+1]
     [Volume at day-1, volume at day 0, return at day+1]]
```

I would like to find rules, that define the ranges of price at day-1 and price at day 0 to predict the price at day+1 in the following way:

```
If price is below 500 for day-1 AND price is above 200 at day 0
The average return at day+1 is 1.05 (5%)
```

or

```
If price is below 500 for day-1 AND price is above 200 at day 0
AND If volume is above 200 for day-1 AND volume is below 800 at day 0
The average return at day+1 is 1.09 (9%)
```

I am not looking for any solutions but just for the general strategy how to approach this problem.

Is ML useful here at all, or would it be better done using a for loop iterating through all values to find the rules? I am considering random forest, would that be a viable option?

Comment: I would say https://stats.stackexchange.com/ is a better option to make your particular question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Random forests can be used for regression.

They will have a tendency to predict the average though, because of the forest aggregation. Regular decision trees may be a bit more "decisive".